# access to "super" through pointer to class's object

Tags: iphone

I have some class `SimpleButton`. It is a Child of `Button` class. `Button` class has some method, which is overridden in `SimpleButton`. Now, if I whant to get access to this method from `simpleButton`, I just need to call `[super someMethod];` But how to get access to it from outside of `simpleButton`? I tried:

```
SimpleButton *button;
[(Button*)button.superclass someMethod];
```

but this does not works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it like that. If you've overridden a method in a subclass then you have changed the publicly available method of that class to be the one in your implementation. You would have to have a separate method which just calls the super implementation:

Say you've overridden method `foo`. Create a new method, `superFoo`

```
[button superFoo];
```

Which internally does this:

```
-(void)superFoo
{
    [super foo];
}
```

However, if you need to do this sort of thing then you probably need to rethink why you have overridden the method in the first place. Perhaps you should have a new method on your subclass instead which does the unique parts and calls the super implementation itself, rather than overriding.

Comment: Tnx for response. I already thought about that, but this a little durty. It seems I should rethink my program's logic.